is firebase cloud messaging must take web notification permission?
i want to use firebase cloud messaging instead of WebSocket so to listen on events on front end and display element based on this but when i turnoff notification permission in chrome browser i don't receive any thing , so must i allow notification permission on chrome ? and what can i do if i want user even he didn't allow it to keep receiving notification ?
this is how i listen to notification
 this.fireMessaging.messages.subscribe((payload) => { console.log(payload);});
i am using angular/fire package
